# Loop through multiple csv files and write one column into new output csv

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have 251 CSV files in a folder.  They are named "returned UDTs 1-12-13.csv", "returned UDTs 1-13-13.csv.  The dates are not consecutive, however.  For example holidays and weekends may have missing dates, so the next file may be "returned UDTs 1-17-13.csv".  Each file has one column of data.  I need to extract each column and append into one column in one new output csv file.  I want to write a python script to do so.  In a dummy folder with 3 dummy csv files (csv1.csv, csv2.csv, and csv3.csv) I created the following script that works:

```
 import csv, os, sys

out_csv = r"C:\OutCSV\csvtest.csv"
path = r"C:\CSV_test"


fout=open(out_csv,"a")
# first file:
for line in open(path + "\csv1.csv"):
    fout.write(line)
# now the rest:    
for num in range(2,4):
    f = open(path + "\csv"+str(num)+".csv")
    f.next() # skip the header
    for line in f:
         fout.write(line)
    f.close() # dont know if needed
fout.close()
```

The issue is the date in the file name and how to deal with it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If there is only one column in the input files and one in the output files, it is irrlevant that they are CSV files - you should be able to just concatenate them together.

Comment: If you use 3 nested loops, `for year=2000..2014;for month=1..12;for day=1..31; if file$year$month$day exists concatenate it; end;end;end`

Comment: I figured it out.  I renamed all files to ReturnedUDTs1,ReturnedUDTs2, etc and the the above script worked.